# Specflow feature files - Possible to have multi line example

Tags: c#, specflow, feature-file

I was wondering if within a Scenario Outline it would be possible to have a new line for parameter names
e.g.

```
  Scenario Outline: Login
        Given <I> <am> <on> <the> <Office> <Portal> <link>
        When I have entered my CRM credentials and sign in
        Then I will be logged in
        Examples: 
        |I   |am   | on| the | //newline
        |data|data |data|data|
        |Office |Portal |link|
        |data|data |data|data|
```

I assume no, as I'm not sure how it would differentiate between the lines. The reason why I need this is for lengthy scenarios that have quite a lot of parameters (e.g. 25 params).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible.

**Documentation**. It is stated in [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/docs/reference) specification that examples section should be a table with single header row and all other rows with data:

> The table must have a header row corresponding to the variables in the
>   Scenario Outline steps.
>
> *Each* of the rows below will create a new Scenario, filling in the
>   variable values.

**Technical part**. Specflow uses [Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/gherkin) language parser which parses feature files into AST (Abstract Syntax Tree). This parser reads input file lines one by one and produces token for each line. From [TokenScanner](https://github.com/cucumber/gherkin-dotnet/blob/fce89eee68fc4f23639808dab4faeabdaa92028a/Gherkin/TokenScanner.cs) source code:

> The scanner reads a gherkin doc (typically read from a .feature file)
>   and creates a token *for each line*. The tokens are passed to the
>   parser, which outputs an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree).

Parser then reads tokens one by one and determines what kind of *line* this token is related to. When it finds examples line, then it looks for single header line (Examples_Definition) followed by examples. If you will do something like this

```
    |I      |am     | on   | the |
    |data   |data   |data  |data |
    |Office |Portal |link  |
    |data   |data   |data  |
```

then the third line will be treated as a examples row with an incorrect number of cells.

Actually how the parser would be able to understand whether you have simple data row or headers row? All examples data are represented as strings. Aand `Office` is a completely valid value for `I` column. OK in this particular sample you have 3 columns in bottom table definition part. But if there would be four columns too?

```
    |I      |am     | on   | the |
    |data   |data   |data  |data |
    |Office |Portal |link  | foo |
    |data   |data   |data  |data |
```

There is no way to define second header row for the parser.

**Readabiltiy**. And frankly speaking, such multiline tables would be unreadable for people. It would be very hard to correlate third scenario outline parts from bottom and top part of examples table. But readability is the main feature of gherkin and Specflow. Consider redesigning your tests if you have to provide so many parameters for the scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Multiline parameters for examples are not possible with Gherkin (the language you use to write your Scenarios).
Every line in the examples section will be a separate scenario/test.

If you have that much parameters, the best practice is to split the Scenario Outline in multiple Outlines and work with default values.